# Android layout view id name issue

Tags: android

I recently faced an issue when i named a view as `android:id="@+id/TextView1"` and the code

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
```

was returning wrong view even though there were no warnings given for the naming convention.
When i changed the name to text_view_1 it worked.

I know the usual naming convention is all small case like `android:id="@+id/text_view_1"` or camel case like `android:id="@+id/textView1"`

Is there any documented resource which explains the issue or any answer for it?
Also i want to know what m stands for in the variable name which i often see in open source code. e.g.

```
TextView mTextView;
```

Its a noob question but i couldn't find a answer anywhere.

Comment: I think the problem was not in upper-case first letter. It's hard to say now what was wrong. But if it wasn't null, it did found something. And if it was in your.package.name.R than it was definitely assigned by you. I had a practice of using such names created by fellow coders and it worked fine.

Comment: What is your target version?

Comment: @ Ilango J, target version is API 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to clean and build you project.

Android [coding syle guide](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) states:

- Non-public, non-static field names start with m.
- Static field names start with s.
- Other fields start with a lower case letter.
- Public static final fields (constants) are ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES.

It would be `private ImageButton mButtonStart;` or `private static sSingletonThing;`

That convention is by the way only required to be used if you want to contribute to the Android sourcecode, you can write your own apps in any style.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and pointing to the official resource.

Comment: you can try these things if they worked:

1. delete "gen" folder
2. clean and build your project
3. remove if "import android.R" statement if any

Answer (score 2):

Thats a known issue in Eclipse. It was returning the wrong view because there must have been some referencing issues. Generally cleaning the project or restarting eclipse helps.

And regarding the prefix m, 'm' is a naming convention used to denote private member variables and methods.

Comment: R.java is not refreshed when that referencing issue happens, cleaning the project or refreshing it, regenerates the R file and hence the issue is resolved!

Comment: Thanks. I will do a clean build next time if i encounter the same problem.